# Почему данный код работает без ошибок?

Tags: строки, rust

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello");
    let hello = &s[5..];
    println!("{}", hello);
}
```

Пожалуйста, объясните почему данный код работает без ошибок (правда ничего не выводит, но ошибки выхода за пределы содержания нет).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Взятие полного слайса может выполняться таким образом (в данном случае неважно массив это или строка):

```
fn get_slice(v:&Vec<u8>) -> &[u8]{
    &v[..] // эквивалентно &v[0..]
}
```

Если бы взятие пустого слайса после последнего элемента было запрещено, то передача на вход этой функции пустого вектора вызвала бы панику.

Вводить дополнительные условия проверки индексов и длинны в данном случае было бы не рационально, так как индексация часто используется в циклах. Усложнение условий проверки может оказать негативное влияние на производительность программ.

К тому же этот случай полностью [покрыт тестами](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b7c6e8f1805cd8a4b0a1c1f22f17a89e9e2cea23/src/libcore/tests/slice.rs#L524), так что очевидно есть достаточно серьезные причины для такого поведения. Еще например, это может быть нужно для упрощения проверок индексов массивов в макросах.

Если вам интересна внутренняя механика проверки индексов, то вот как выглядит [метод структуры `Range` для получения слайса](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#2090-2148):

```
unsafe fn get_unchecked(self, slice: &[T]) -> &[T] {
    from_raw_parts(slice.as_ptr().offset(self.start as isize), self.end - self.start)
}
```

Обратите внимание как вычисляется длинна слайса - это последний аргумент функции `from_raw_parts()`:

```
self.end - self.start
```

Это выражение может быть вычислено без переполнения при условии:

```
self.end >= self.start
```

Т.е. функция `get_unchecked()` будет нормально работать в вашем случае (когда `self.end == self.start`).

Если поискать место где происходит проверка индексов слайса можно увидеть и само условие:

```
fn get(self, slice: &[T]) -> Option<&[T]> {
    if self.start > self.end || self.end > slice.len() {
        None
    } else {
        unsafe {
            Some(self.get_unchecked(slice))
        }
    }
}
```

В вашем случае конечно используются методы структуры `RangeFrom`, но они просто вызывают методы `Range` c условием `self.end == slice.len()`.
В результате получается, что выражения `s[5..]` и `s[5..5]` допустимы, а `s[6..]` и `s[6..6]` уже вызывают ошибку.

PS: Насчет отказаться от использования индексов со строками - совершенно верное решение, т.к. индекс можете попасть внутрь utf-8 символа, а это приведет к падению программы. В документации есть [предупреждение](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/2018-edition/ch08-02-strings.html#slicing-strings) об этом. Кроме того есть специальный итератор по символам [`chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars).

Answer (score 2):

А почему должна быть ошибка? В строке пять байт, мы просим подстроку с пятого байта - получаем пустую подстроку с `.len()` равной нулю.

Вот если попросим `[6..]`, то будет выход за пределы массива и паника.

Comment: Потому что "5" - это длинна среза и обращение к этому индексу в других языках (Java, например) приводит к ошибке. Кроме того, это ведь не массив байтов, а символов (вроде как). Если всё же это байты, тогда, пожалуйста, поясните как понять это (байты это или не байты). Во всех срезах по индексу получаем байты?

Comment: Обращение к индексу 5 (`array[5]`) и в ржавчине приведет к панике. Только тут у нас именно что взятие среза - это другая операция с другой семантикой (почти идентичной, например, питоновским срезам).

Comment: Строка в расте внутри представлена именно как массив байт (т.е. `String` хранится аналогично с `Vec<u8>`, а не `Vec<char>`) и индексируются в строковых срезах именно байты.

Comment: Ага. Понятно, как храняться данные строковых срезов. А что собой представляет последний элемент этого массива? `\0` - т.е. как в Си? Последний символ - нулевой байт - индикатор конца строки?

Comment: Нет, ржавые строки хранят длину как число и могут содежать в данных `'\0'`. Так что последний элемент ржавой строки - это просто последний байт ее данных. В случае пустого среза никаких байт данных в нем нет вообще. Совместимые с Си строки находятся в стандартной библиотеке - https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html

Answer (score 0):

Взятие среза, начиная с индекса последнего элемента допустимо, т.к. внутреннее хранение данных среза и проверки индексов это допускают.
Для предотвращение возможных ошибок наилучшим решением будет отказаться от использования индексов при работе со срезами (т.е. не использованить индекс для поступа к элементу среза).

```
fn main() {
    //let s = String::from("hello");
    let s = [1..10];
    for i in 0..s.len() + 1 {
        println!("slice = {:?}", &s[i..]);
    }

    for element in s.iter() {
        println!("slice = {:?}", element);
    }
}
```

Comment: "в данном случае решением будет" - не понятно о решении какой проблемы идет речь? вопрос был про "почему не паникует...".

Comment: "Обращение к пятому индесу среза состоящих из пяти элементов допустимо" - нет, именно обращение к индексу среза [не допустимо](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=054ddaaba90116dd725d90806b048246&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015). А вот "взятие среза, начиная с индекса последнего элемента" - допустимо. Логика в том что мы просим "дай мне все элементы, начиная с индекса последнего элемента", т.е. "дай мне пустое множество".